# How to connect jsp, MySQL with android studio through Tomcat

Tags: android, jsp

This is my code for Android Studio and it gives a ClassNotFoundException:

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/admin?&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=106",
                "haproxy_check",
                "");

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT access_name, access_code FROM user_login where user_login_id='2650'");

        while (rs.next()) {
            x = rs.getString("access_name");
            y = rs.getString("access_code");
        }
```

I've tried some of the options like using mysql-connector and importing it to android studio but I don't know if I'm doing it right.

I don't have Tomcat locally on my desktop but I can access the database because the server was up and also through network.

All I want is that when I'm using a real android phone, I can connect it to the database through internet.

Comment: Please post your console with error logs.

Comment: I'm using try/catch. I don't know specifically where can I find the error logs. But when I removed the " Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")", it gives me "No suitable driver". And when I include that, it goes to "ClassNotFoundException"

Comment: In your catch block use `printStackTrace()` to get the error logs

Comment: I used e.printStackTrace() and in what window log can I see the error? Run, TODO, Messages, Android Monitor, Terminal, Event Log, or Gradle Console

Comment: `Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'. > JSR/RET are not supported with computeFrames option` _This my gradle console error_